# How and when to appropriately use weakref in Python

Tags: python, circular-reference

I have some code where instances of classes have parent<->child references to each other, e.g.:

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = None
        self.children = {}

    def AddChild(self, name, child):
        child.parent = self
        self.children[name] = child


def Run():
    root, c1, c2 = Node(), Node(), Node()
    root.AddChild('first', c1)
    root.AddChild('second', c2)


Run()
```

I *think* this creates circular references such that `root`, `c1` and `c2` won't be freed after Run() is completed, right?.  So, how do get them to be freed?  I think I can do something like `root.children.clear()`, or `self.parent = None` - but what if I don't know when to do that?

Is this an appropriate time to use the weakref module?  What, exactly, do I weakref'ify?  the `parent` attribute?  The `children` attribute?  The whole object?  All of the above?  I see talk about the WeakKeyDictionary and weakref.proxy, but its not clear to me how they should be used, if at all, in this case.

This is also on Python 2.4 (can't upgrade).

**Update: Example and Summary**

What objects to weakref-ify depends on which object can live without the other, and what objects depend on each other.  The object that lives the longest should contain weakrefs to the shorter-lived objects.  Similarly, weakrefs should not be made to dependencies - if they are, the dependency could silently disappear even though it is still needed.

If, for example, you have a tree structure, `root`, that has children, `kids`, but can exist *without* children, then the `root` object should use weakrefs for its `kids`.  This is also the case if the child object depends on the existence of the parent object.  Below, the child object *requires* a parent in order to compute its depth, hence the strong-ref for `parent`.  The members of the `kids` attribute are optional, though, so weakrefs are used to prevent a circular reference.

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.parent = None
        self.kids = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()

    def GetDepth(self):
        root, depth = self, 0
        while root:
            depth += 1
            root = root.parent
        return depth


root = Node()
root.kids['one'] = Node()
root.kids['two'] = Node()
```

To flip the relationship around, we have something like the below.  Here, the `Facade` classes require a `Subsystem` instance to work, so they use a strong-ref to the subsystem they need.  `Subsystem`s, however, don't require a `Facade` to work.  `Subsystem`s just provide a way to notify `Facade`s about each other's actions.

```
class Facade:

  def __init__(self, subsystem):
    self.subsystem = subsystem
    subsystem.Register(self)


class Subsystem:

    def __init__(self):
        self.notify = []

    def Register(self, who):
        self.notify.append(weakref.proxy(who))


sub = Subsystem()
cli = Facade(sub)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yep, weakref's excellent here. Specifically, instead of:

```
self.children = {}
```

use:

```
self.children = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()
```

Nothing else needs change in your code. This way, when a child has no other differences, it just goes away -- and so does the entry in the parent's `children` map that has that child as the value.

Avoiding reference loops is up high on a par with implementing caches as a motivation for using the `weakref` module. Ref loops won't kill you, but they may end up clogging your memory, esp. if some of the classes whose instances are involved in them define `__del__`, since that interferes with the `gc`'s module ability to dissolve those loops.

Comment: Also, if you are sure you won't be needing the cyclic gc, you can disable it for a small performance increase.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  Is there a specific reason to weakref `children` rather than `parent`?  Would the effect be the same?  What would happen if `parent` was weakref'd, too?  In the case of a double-linked list, should `prev`, `next`, or both be weakrefs?

Comment: This is bad suggestion. All children in the example will be destructed just after return from `Run()`. In general you almost always bind a root of structure to variable, so the right way is to use `weakref` for `parent`, but not `children`.

Comment: I also found this message which recommends weakrefs towards the root rather than leaves: http://74.125.155.132/search?q=cache:http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-March/705913.html

Comment: The point is not "parent" or "child" but "which one can exist without the other". In this toy example there's little indication, except that we _know_ that the parent _can_ exist without children (because it starts that way!) but we don't know if the converse is true -- maybe the children intrinsically need some services from the parent, and if so they should normal-reference AKA strong-reference it. @Denis, of course everything (parent AND children) gets destroyed at end of Run in this toy example -- d'oh: that's what **makes** it toy, and doesn't invalidate my suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I added an example/summary that combines yours and Denis's answers.  I also marked it as community wiki in case I've misunderstood something.

Answer (score 21):

I suggest using `child.parent = weakref.proxy(self)`. This is a good solution to avoid circular references when the lifetime of `parent` covers the lifetime of `child`. Use `self.children = weakref.WeakValueDictionary()` (as Alex Martelli suggested) when the lifetime of `child` covers the lifetime of `parent`. But never use weak references when both `parent` and `child` can be alive independently. Here after these rules are illustrated with examples.

Use a weakly referenced parent if you bind the root to a name and pass it around, while children are accessed from it:

```
def Run():
    root, c1, c2 = Node(), Node(), Node()
    root.AddChild('first', c1)
    root.AddChild('second', c2)
    return root  # only root refers to c1 and c2 after return, 
                 # so this references should be strong
```

Use weakly referenced children if you bind each child to a name and pass them around, while root is accessed from them:

```
def Run():
    root, c1, c2 = Node(), Node(), Node()
    root.AddChild('first', c1)
    root.AddChild('second', c2)
    return c1, c2
```

Don’t use weak references in this case:

```
def Run():
    root, c1, c2 = Node(), Node(), Node()
    root.AddChild('first', c1)
    root.AddChild('second', c2)
    return c1
```

Comment: There's plenty of cases in which either or both of child and parent can be alive without the other _as long as other entities yet hold references to them_; that's when you might want to use mutually weak references (those other external references will do the job of keeping the entities alive exactly as long as needed).

Comment: **"I suggest using `child.parent = weakref.proxy(self)`."** _Thisss._ This is the canonical approach for the common case of one long-lived `parent` containing multiple short-lived `child`-ren. Alexis' solution is more applicable to the edge case of multiple long-lived `child`-ren "owning" one short-lived `parent`, which I only rarely see in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to clarify which references can be weak. The following approach is general, but I use the doubly-linked tree in all examples.

Logical Step 1.

You need to ensure that there are strong references to keep all the objects alive as long as you need them. It could be done in many ways, for example by:

- [direct names]: a named reference to each node in the tree
- [container]: a reference to a container that stores all the nodes
- [root + children]: a reference to the root node, and references from each node to its children
- [leaves + parent]: references to all the leaf nodes, and references from each node to its parent

Logical Step 2.

Now you add references to represent information, if required.

For instance, if you used [container] approach in Step 1, you still have to represent the edges. An edge between nodes A and B can be represented with a single reference; it can go in either direction. Again, there are many options, for example:

- [children]: references from each node to its children
- [parent]: a reference from each node to its parent
- [set of sets]: a set containing 2-element sets; each 2-element contains references to nodes of one edge

Of course, if you used [root + children] approach in Step 1, all your information is already fully represented, so you skip this step.

Logical Step 3.

Now you add references to improve performance, if desired.

For instance, if you used [container] approach in Step 1, and [children] approach in Step 2, you might desire to improve the speed of certain algorithms, and add references between each each node and its parent. Such information is logically redundant, since you could (at a cost in performance) derive it from existing data.

---

*All the references in Step 1 must be strong*.

*All the references in Steps 2 and 3 may be weak or strong*. There is no advantage to using strong references. There is an advantage to using weak references until you know that cycles are no longer possible. Strictly speaking, once you know that cycles are impossible, it makes no difference whether to use weak or strong references. But to avoid thinking about it, you might as well use exclusively weak references in the Steps 2 and 3.